# iOS: Custom navigation bar with breadcrumb trail?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uinavigationbar

I would like to implement a custom `UINavigationBar` with a breadcrumb trail at the bottom. So I'm wondering if it's possible to increase the siez of the bar to get this result.
Also, is it possible to animate the breadcrumb trail with the animation of the view being pushed or popped?

[image]

I'm mainly interested in a solution with `UIKit`, I don't know if I can do this with `SwiftUI` yet.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend the UINavigationController class to include a progress view, here's a question with a similar request (and a solution): [Showing a UIProgressView inside or on top of a UINavigationController's UINavigationBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19211999/showing-a-uiprogressview-inside-or-on-top-of-a-uinavigationcontrollers-uinaviga/19231862)